# Where from it is faster to load images in the ListView?

Tags: android, imageview, assets, android-sdcard

I fill the **ListView** from **DataBase** by using **SimpleCursorAdapter** where I am overriding **getView** method. By this method for each item I am loading the small image from my telephone.

Where do you suggest to store my small images (20 images x 1 kB)?

- in DB (it is on my SDCARD);
- in the folder on SDCARD;
- in assets;
- in raw folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images that you are including with your project should go in one of the drawable folders, not assets or raw, for instance  `yourProjectFolder/res/drawable-mdpi/`

You can provide higher / lower resolution images in the ldpi, and hdpi folders.

As to whether you should use the drawables folder or some form of SD storage it comes down to whether or not you may ever need to change the images. If you include them in your project drawable folder then you will be unable to make any changes to them after compile time. If you store them on the SD then you have the option to go back and download different / more pictures to use.

So it just depends on if you'll ever need to the option to add more, or change the images that you're using.

Comment: I am not going to use -mdpi/-ldpi/-hdpi images. Are there any difference in performance between drawable and raw folder?
I am using the next syntax: `imgFlag.setImageResource(R.raw.image)`

Comment: I don't know if there are any differences in performance. I do know that drawable was created for images so it is probably a good idea to use it instead of raw even if just from the standpoint of having it be easiest to figure out for someone unfamiliar with it, or for yourself after some period of time. You don't have to use one of the dpi qualifiers in order to use drawable. YourProject/res/drawable/ is a valid folder to use too.

Comment: I have made several tests and so, you are right.
Receiving images from drawable folder was always faster on 30% then from raw folder.
Thanks!